# FullCalendar showing unnecessary double data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fullcalendar, laravel-livewire

I'm making a calendar for a swimming club using FullCalendar.

A swimmer can be asked to take a supplement which is described in a table called `swimmerSupplement`.

If two swimmers have to take the exact same supplement on the same time it shows double on the calendar. It's a calendar view for a coach, so not every swimmer his supplement needs to be displayed only one for the group.

Is it possible to show only one message like: "Calcium 2 grams" instead of it showing two identical blocks?

```
foreach ($swimmerSupplements as $supplement) {
    $eventsSwimmerSupplement[] = [
    'title' => $supplement->supplement->name,
    'allDay' => true,
    'start' => $supplement->date,
    'color' => 'red' ];
}
```

After this I return view() with the array that was just made.

Here you can see the UML diagram.

[image: uml diagram]

Comment: You'll need to provide a [mre] of the issue. We can't  see your source data, we can't see what's in `$swimmerSupplements`, or what you're doing with `$eventsSwimmerSupplement[]` after this code you've shown us. We'd like to help, but at the moment there isn't enough info for anyone to diagnose the root cause of the issue. It would also help a lot if you tell us the results of your efforts to debug it so far, to narrow down the issue. You can [edit] your question. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Question: why would you want it to only show the supplement once? Surely it's useful to know if two different people need to take the supplement? Surely you'd want to show the swimmer's name on the calendar against each entry, as well as just the supplement name? Then you'll know the number of people who need to take it, who they are, and the total quantity of each supplement which would be required on each day. Obviously I don't know your business process but that would seem like more useful information to display, on the face of it.

Comment: Ok. Well that tells us a bit about the structure of the database, but it doesn't tell us what _actual_ data you've got, or how you're querying it and getting into PHP, or what you're doing with it afterwards - i.e. all the things I actually asked for, in order for us to understand how you end up with the result you're currently seeing :-)

Comment: You also haven't replied to my question about why you want to make this change, as it doesn't appear to make a lot of sense from an end-user point of view. If I was viewing your calendar, I'd want to know which swimmer has to take which supplements, on which day. It wouldn't be useful just to know that supplement X has to be taken. That doesn't seem very useful, unless I know _who_ needs to take it.